# cy.session to make a login into a backend system

Tags: cypress

the problem I am facing is when I save my credentials for login using sessions as the image below:
[image]

everything looks good but the issue is on the IT brackets with the endpoint url:
[image]
result that this endpont url is the url once you are logged into the backend system but as you see this url changes everytime you make a new logging causing cypress cannot access. So dont know how to solve this problem:
[image]

```
/(S(xxxxxxxxxxx))/
```

in the URL this part is the one that changes

I tried to research the issue but with no success. I expect this issue can have a solution or a way to make the endpoint url that is changable like a unique url.

Comment: Why not to establish second cy.visit (from it() ) in cy.session?

Comment: Tomas, because session only calls the code once. So only first test would visit. Second test would have blank `/about` page. Unless you also mean turn off isolation (generally not recommended).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the login click redirects you to the dynamic URL (it should do, otherwise how do you know what it is?), just save it to a variable/alias.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('login', () => {
    ...
    cy.getLogin().click()
    cy.url()
      .should('contain', '/(S(')  // make sure this is the dynamic URL
      .as('url')
  })
})

it('test', () => {
  cy.get('@url').then(url => {
    cy.visit(url)
  })
  ...
```